# Printing 2D data matrix barcode using ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I have implemented a label which prints 2D data matrix barcode and the code for it is as follows

```
^XA
^LH0,0
^FO50,50
^BXN,5,200
^FD0101111452628888888888888817170730108880^FS
^FO168,50^AE,18,10^FPH\^FDNAME:^FS
^FO265,50^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FDTEST NAME^FS
^FO168,80^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FDTUID:^FS
^FO265,80^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FD88888888889000^FS
^FO168,110^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FDDATE:^FS
^FO265,110^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FD+4108374-11-11^FS
^FO168,140^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FDAGE:^FS
^FO265,140^AEN,18,10^FPH\^FDTEST LOT^FS
^XZ
```

The barcode is getting printed properly but it is printing with 22 modules but i want it to be 26 modules. Can somebody please help me get this 26 modules.

cheers

Answer (score 3):

After going through doc and reading on the internet to achieve module size of 26x26. The code ia as follows

```
^BXN,4,200,26,26
```